# How to succinctly link files in Ubuntu where the library files have long address

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, linker, fortran

I have installed a free fortran software in ubuntu that I want to use to do some calculations. Now each time I compile I have to use `-I/home/me/dir1/dir2 -L/home/me/dir1/dir2/lib/`    to give the directories where the compiled files and libraries are located. This is rather cumbersome.

Please point me in the right direction: I want to to have a short cut for the long location, for example how can I define `myloc = /home/me/dir1/dir2` so that when I compile I would just type `gfortran myprog.f90 -I/myloc -L/myloc` . Please provide some links to where I can find such examples. Is this called scripting language? I vaguely know that I might have to write some commands in ./bashrc or ./profile.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `.bashrc` (type `nano ~/.bashrc` in terminal), enter the following lines

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/me/dir1/dir2/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/dir1/dir2
```

save & exit, then type `source ~/.bashrc` and then you should not have to add `-I${...} -L${...}` to your compilation. This should work, as gfortran will look in `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directories for the appropriate files.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this as soon as I get to work tomorrow. Is this what is called scripting? Has it got a special name like bash scripting or ubuntu scripting like as in unix scripting. I want to be able to search for the keyword and read and understand instead of just solving this specific problem. Again than kyou

Comment: This is not what I would call scripting, it is setting user-defined environment controls & variables through `bash`, which is a command-line interpreter to the *nix OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can define environment variables and use those during compilation.  For example, say:

```
INCDIR=/home/me/dir1/dir2
LIBDIR=/home/me/dir1/dir2/lib
```

and execute `gfortran` by saying:

```
gfortran myprog.f90 -I${INCDIR} -L${LIBDIR}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please specify where you'd put the environmental variables.

Comment: Assuming you use `bash`, put it in your `~/.bashrc`.